# 'my_layer' object has no attribute '_dynamic'

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I want to design a model by tensorflow2.0,when Icompile the model,it report an error

'my_layer' object has no attribute '_dynamic'
the code is

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class my_layer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,classes):
        self.conv1 = layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),strides=1,padding='same')
        self.conv2 = layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),strides=1,padding='same')
        self.conv3 = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding='same')
        self.conv4 = layers.Conv2D(classes, (3, 3), strides=1, padding='same')
        self.bn = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.glbavgpool = layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()
        self.fc = layers.Dense(classes)

    def call(self,inputs):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.bn(x)
        x = keras.activations.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = keras.activations.relu(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.conv4(x)
        x = self.bn(x)
        x = self.glbavgpool(x)
        out = self.fc(x)
        return out


class mymodel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,classes):
        super(mymodel,self).__init__()
        self.ml = my_layer(classes=classes)

    def call(self,inputs):
        return self.ml(inputs)
```

then I put all the custom layers to my_model, it worked. I think it's probably the wrong way to use mylayer.

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing this error because you forgot to call the superclass constructor in your `my_layer` class. Add this following line:

```py
class my_layer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,classes):
        super(my_layer, self).__init__()  # <-- Remember to call superclass constructor!!

        self.conv1 = layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),strides=1,padding='same')
        self.conv2 = layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),strides=1,padding='same')
        self.conv3 = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), strides=1, padding='same')
        self.conv4 = layers.Conv2D(classes, (3, 3), strides=1, padding='same')
        self.bn = layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.glbavgpool = layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()
        self.fc = layers.Dense(classes)
```